# Is 'Our mother add vegetables to the food because they are good for us' grammatically correct?

Tags: definite-article, collocations

1. Do native speakers speak like this?

> Our mother adds vegetables to the food because they're good for us.

2. Is it ok to put 'the' before food?

Comment: Usually one would say "*to* ***our*** *food*" since you are stating she is cooking for you ("*good for us*"), without the last bit, it might mean she is cooking for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sentence is grammatical. You could say

to the food

to food she makes for us

to the food she makes for us

to our food